# What is the equivalent of "aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/folder-name/" in AWS JS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sdk-js

Running into a problem where listObjectsV2 returns all of the objects on a deepest level of all folders.
I need only first level of those. The same way as ls would give you

Ideas appreciated

Comment: Set the delimiter to `/` to disable the recursion.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm! You got it